# How does an XSLT utilize prefixed attributes from a separate source?

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, schema, xslt-2.0

I take an XML file and transform it to a fixed width utilizing XSLT, yet I'm forced to use attributes of a certain prefix. For the transformation to function properly I have to upload my finished XSLT file to a website, run it, and the website produces the necessary fixed width file.
What I want to know is how can I perform the same transformation without uploading the XSLT? What kind of file (Schema, XSL) must I produce and link, to make sense of these attributes? 
For example:

```
<!-- note_XML.xml -->    
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <note>
      <to>Tove</to>
      <from>Jani</from>
      <heading>Reminder</heading>
      <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
    </note>`
```

XSL:

```
<!-- note_XSL.xsl -->    
<?xml version-"1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet smlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result prefixes="xs"
        xmlns:joe="urn:com.website/joe" version="2.0">

        <xsl:template match="/">
            <Case joe:separator="&#xd;&#xa;">

                <Tape>
                    <PersonReceiving joe:fixedLength="4">
                        <xsl:value-of select="/note/to"/>
                    </PersonReceiving>

                    <Sender joe:fixedLength="4" joe:align="right">
                        <xsl:value-of select="/note/from"/>
                   </Sender>
                   etc...
                </Tape>
            </Case>
        </xsl:template>
    <xsl:stylesheet>
```

Notice the 'joe' prefixed attributes, what do I do to make sense of them without having to upload the XSLT and have the server do it for me? I'd prefer to do the work in a separate file versus adding variables/functions to the same note_XSL.xsl stylesheet.

I'm currently working on oXygen, the xml editor.

Comment: If you want to do your own transformation, you need to forget about the prefixed attributes and write your own code for padding the values to a fixed width.

Comment: I think you're reading some significance into the namespace prefixes that isn't there. Handling attributes in a namespace is exactly the same as handling attributes in no namespace. There's no earthly reason that the presence of prefixed attributes should constrain where you run the transformation.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  Now how do I handle the attributes? I'm sure I could create a second XSL in which the attributes are declared/defined, but then how do I link up the two stylesheets? Do I run the the new  stylesheet as a second transformation?

Comment: I finally created a second XSLT file that performs a transformation on the output of the first XSLT; works like a charm!  Thank you both for your input.